# Springboot Integration test runtime error - ClassCastException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a controller I am writing tests for. Everything seems to compile fine but then I get a runtime error saying the below. I do not remember any place where I cast my DTO to a string. The stacktrace reveals that this "ResultActions response = mockMvc.perform(post("/app/api/agency/signup")
.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.content(mapper.writeValueAsString(agency))" is the problematic line but I am not sure how.

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.zshift.io.dto.records.AgencyDTORecord cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (com.zshift.io.dto.records.AgencyDTORecord is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException
    at com.zshift.io.tests.agency.AgencyIntegrationTest.testAgencySignup(AgencyIntegrationTest.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.zshift.io.dto.records.AgencyDTORecord cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (com.zshift.io.dto.records.AgencyDTORecord is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.zshift.io.tests.agency.AgencyIntegrationTest.testAgencySignup(AgencyIntegrationTest.java:77)
```

The controller looks something like this.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/signup", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON }, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public ResponseEntity addAgency(@RequestBody AgencyDTORecord record) throws AlreadyExistsException {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.saveAgency(record), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

My DTO class looks something like this

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class AgencyDTORecord {
    
    private String agencyAbout;
    private String agencyAddress;
    private String agencyEmail;
    private String agencyLocation;
    private String agencyName;
    private String agencyPhone;
    private String agencyLatitude;
    private String agencyLongitude;
    private String agencySecret;
    private String agencyPostCode;
    private Long agencyID;
    private String agencyRoleName;
    private String agencyStaffName;
    private String agencyStaff;
}
```

Here is my test class

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = AgencyController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AgencyIntegrationTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @MockBean
    private AgencyService service;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    
    private AgencyDTORecord agency;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void init()
    {
        agency = new AgencyDTORecord();
        agency.setAgencyAbout("For testing");
        agency.setAgencyAddress("test address");
        agency.setAgencyEmail("agency@test.com");
        agency.setAgencyLatitude("1000");
        agency.setAgencyLongitude("2000");
        agency.setAgencyName("The Test Agency");
        agency.setAgencyPhone("3000");
        agency.setAgencyPostCode("CT92LA");
        agency.setAgencyRoleName("Admin");
        agency.setAgencySecret("1234");
        agency.setAgencyStaff("Alao");
        agency.setAgencyID(Long.parseLong("0"));
        agency.setAgencyStaffName("Alao Akala");
    }
    
    @Test
public void testAgencySignup() throws Exception {
    given(service.saveAgency(any())).will(invocation -> invocation.getArgument(0));
    
    ResultActions response = mockMvc.perform(post("/app/api/agency/signup")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(agency))
    );
    
    response.andExpect(status().isCreated())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.agencyName", is(agency.getAgencyName())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.agencyPhone", is(agency.getAgencyPhone())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed. I used Gson to convert the agency DTO to Json before passing it as a content object.